# What will happen if you complete a stamp card in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2

Within the local play area called the shoal in Splatoon 2, you can play with local players.

I have seen a stamp card where you can collect stamps on but

**How to collect them and what will happen if you complete a stamp card?**

I can't find this anywhere and I don't know why it is there at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you complete a stamp card, you will get a **Crust Bucket  ticket**.
<sup>[Source](https://wiki.denfaminicogamer.jp/Splatoon2/%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3)(but the source is written in Japanese)</sup>

Comment: What does the Crust Bucket ticket do?

Comment: it gives a buff like 2x more money or a higher change for a spefic skill like swim speed up